# Call setImageDrawable from RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-imageview, remoteview, shapedrawable

I have done this in an Activity and it works perfectly.

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
mDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
mDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(height);

myImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
```

Now I want to do the same thing in a widget (inside `onUpdate`) and I have to use `RemoteViews` to access the image.

How do I call the `setImageDrawable` of an `ImageView` from `RemoteViews`? All the remote views methods seems to take a `Bitmap`.

Comment: I am stuck on the same thing. Can you please guide me on how did you set the color of the shape. I even can't find `setXYZ()`. In the end I had to post a new question all together: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464535/setting-gradientdrawable-through-remoteview. Please see if you can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RemoteViews` are built from XML resource descriptors. You can not use code to build them.

You need to do something like this:

Create a layout:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/myshapedrawable">
</ImageView>
```

Then define a new [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) named `myshapedrawable.xml` (in res/drawables folder):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="200" android:height="100"/>
    <solid android:color="0xff74AC23"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Will this allow me to change the shape color for example at run time? I want the user to define the color from the widget configuration activity.

Comment: Yes, via `remoteViews.setXYZ(viewId, "setColor", value)`. You need to set ID of the view in you XML in order to access it.

Comment: It almost works perfect with one more issue. I set the `src` property to `myshapedrawable` and it works perfectly. So I wanted to change the color of it but I can only set an Id for the `ImageView` and it doesn't have a `setColor` method. How do I call the `setColor` method of the src ?

Comment: You mean add an id to the shape in drawables? Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Tried to edit the post, the color is incorrect. Should be `#ff74AC23`

Comment: Thanks, this is working! With round corners and the ripple effect. I'm using an ImageButton with a TextView on top. views.setInt(R.id.image_button, "setColorFilter", Color.parseColor("#ff5252")); Make sure to use <solid android:color="@color/white"/> as background.

Answer (score 16):

You can change color of ImageView image in "RemoteViews" by doing this:

```
remoteviews.setInt(viewid, "setColorFilter", color);
```

Comment: This is right answer, I have set drawable on my view with rounded corner and opacity, with this methode I am able to change color while shape with rounded corners stays yay :)

Comment: Works perfectly! wasted so such time just to find this amazing and simple solution (Y).

Answer (score 3):

```
after modify drawable :



 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
 remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(viewId, bitmap) .
```

Comment: ShapeDrawable cannot be casted to a BitmapDrawable.