# Setting GradientDrawable through RemoteView

Tags: android, drawable

Here is what I want to do: I have a widget and I want to set its background depending upon users choice of colors. It has to be a gradient. The backgound is to be set by setting background of the linearLayout. For testing, I did it for a dummy-background as:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.layout, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.widget_background);
```

I have seen this question: [Call setImageDrawable from RemoteViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113133/call-setimagedrawable-from-remoteviews) but I am not able to understand how to implement. I even can't find `setXYZ()` as mentioned there. Here is what I have tried until now:

1. Making a gradient drawable dynamically. In this approach, I am not able to set the background beacause AFAIK all the methods take id of the drawable and I have a drawable object.
2. Tried ImageView as a background (before LinearLayout). It does not provide proper margin to widget. Since the widget text is dynamic, sometimes it goes out of the imageView which is not what I want
3. Making a bg.xml in which I have:

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
          <padding
               android:bottom="1dp"
               android:left="1dp"
               android:right="1dp"
               android:top="1dp" />
          <corners
               android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
               android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
               android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
               android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
   </shape>
   ```

Now I am totally confused and stuck. Can someone help(**probably more of code and less of links**) ASAP? Also, please **don't close this question as already asked**.

Comment: How about using an ``ImageView`` as background layer under your ``LinearLayout``?

Comment: I tried it, but forgot to mention. It does not provide proper margin to widget. Since the widget text is dynamic, sometimes it goes out of the imageView which is not what I want

Answer (score 6):

> Tried ImageView as a background (before LinearLayout). It does not provide proper margin to widget. Since the widget text is dynamic, sometimes it goes out of the imageView which is not what I want

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you use a FrameLayout / RelativeLayout for your root layout, and then put the ImageView inside with fill parent, your image should be exactly the size of your widget.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="6dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widgetBg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    // Other views

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, this is what I'm doing to dynamically change the color & alpha of a rounded corner gradient background.  Then use setImageViewBitmap( ) to apply to the imageview.  Probably there is a better way.

```
public static Bitmap getBackground(int bgColor, int width, int height, Context context) {
    try {
        // convert to HSV to lighten and darken
        int alpha = Color.alpha(bgColor);
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(bgColor, hsv);
        hsv[2] -= .1;
        int darker = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, hsv);
        hsv[2] += .3;
        int lighter = Color.HSVToColor(alpha, hsv);

        // create gradient useng lighter and darker colors
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,new int[] { darker, lighter});
        gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        // set corner size
        gd.setCornerRadii(new float[] {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4});

        // get density to scale bitmap for device
        float dp = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        // create bitmap based on width and height of widget
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(width * dp), Math.round(height * dp),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas =  new Canvas(bitmap);
        gd.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gd.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```