# Dynamic GradientDrawable in RemoteView

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble setting a dynamic background for my widget:

My preferences return a color selected by the user and I would like to apply it to the widget but with a gradient effect. So here's where I am at this moment:

My widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/style_widget"
> ...
```

My Service.java:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);     

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);       

    //this is where I get the color preference value, and create another with some transparency

    int color1 = prefs.getInt("background_color", 00000000);
    int color2 = Color.argb(22, Color.red(color1), Color.green(color1), Color.blue(color1));

    int colors[] = { color1, color2 };

            //Create the GradientDrawable:      
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);
```

If I do :

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_layout, "setBackgroundColor", color1);
```

I get the background color changed, but since gradientDrawable isn't an int, how do I apply it to my background via remoteViews?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've found the answer here:

[Setting GradientDrawable through RemoteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464535/setting-gradientdrawable-through-remoteview)

I created an Imageview filling the whole widget, then created a bitmap using my gradientDrawable, then setted the bitmap to the imageview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/style_widget"
android:padding="0dip" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bck_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

and then in my Service:

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
                    GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, colors);               

float dpi = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
float dp = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Math.round(288 * dp), Math.round(72 * dp), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
gradientDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(5 * (dpi/160));
gradientDrawable.draw(canvas);
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.bck_image, bitmap);
```

(I'm very new to Android so I don't know if the code is well formed but for me it works, in case it can help anyone.)