# How to get color pixel on touch from GradientDrawable

Tags: android, drawable

I have a gradient in view. I want to take a color on pixel on touch.I'm trying to get drawable from view and later bitmap. But it's throw

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    at com.mti.videodiary.activity.SplashActivity.addColorGradient(SplashActivity.java:431)
```

Any ways to help. Thanks

Comment: Your question is **not clear**. But **the error is**. You are `trying to cast a Gradient to a Bitmap`. Which is **not possible**.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bitmap of the `GradientDrawable` and then look for the colour of a specific pixel.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464535/setting-gradientdrawable-through-remoteview):

```
// create bitmap based on width and height of the gradient drawable
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas =  new Canvas(bitmap);
gd.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
gd.draw(canvas);
// bitmap now contains a bitmap of the gradient drawable
```